# Finding maximum substring that is cyclic equivalent

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, string-matching

This is a problem from a programming contest that was held recently.

Two strings a[0..n-1] and b[0..n-1] are called cyclic equivalent if and only if there exists an offset d, such that for all 0 <= i < n, a[i] = b[(i + d) mod n].
Given two strings s[0..L-1] and t[0..L-1] with same length L. You need to find the maximum p such that s[0..p-1] and t[0..p-1] are cyclic equivalent.Print 0 if no such valid p exists.

**Input**

The first line contains an integer T indicating the number of test cases.
For each test case, there are two lines in total. The first line contains s. The second line contains t.
All strings contain only lower case alphabets.

**Output**

Output T lines in total. Each line should start with "Case #: " and followed by the maximum p. Here "#" is the number of the test case starting from 1.
Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 10
1 ≤ L ≤ 1000000

**Example**

Input:

2

abab

baba

abab

baac

Output:

Case 1: 4

Case 2: 3

**Explanation**

Case 1, d can be 1.

Case 2, d can be 2.

**My approach :**

Generate all substrings of S and T in the from S[0...i], T[0...i] and concatenate S[0...i] with itself and check if T is a substring of S[0...i]+S[0...i]. if it a substring then maximum P = i

```
bool isCyclic( string s, string t ){
   string str = s;
   str.append(s);
   if( str.find(t) != string::npos )
       return true;
   return false;
}

int main(){
   string s, t;
   int t1,l, o=1;
   scanf("%d", &t1);
   while( t1-- ){
       cin>>s>>t;
       l = min( s.length(), t.length());
       int i, maxP = 0;
       for( i=1; i<=l; i++ ){
           if( isCyclic(s.substr(0,i), t.substr(0,i)) ){
               maxP = i;
           }
       }
       printf("Case %d: %d\n", o++, maxP);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I knew that this not the most optimized approach for this problem since i got Time Limit Exceeded.I came to know that prefix function can be used to get an O(n) algorithm. I dont know about prefix function.Could someone explain the O(n) approach ?
Contest link http://www.codechef.com/ACMKGP14/problems/ACM14KP3

Comment: You should link to the contest.

Comment: Ty this http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=stringSearching for prefix function. Can you link the contest?

Comment: I updated the question with contest link